# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ânohup.outâ

Tags: spark-submit

I'm recieving the following error when I try to run a spark-submit code in cloudera.

"nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ânohup.outâ"

My spark submit code doesn't seem to run. What could be causing this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript function declaration syntax: var fn = function() {} vs function fn() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn)

Comment: this is a generic JS question (and a duplicate at that), not specific to AngularJS

Comment: This is JavaScript beginner's question. Please follow dome tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The title and the content has different explanations. I'll explain both.

```
var doStuff = function(){}
```

This is a function declaration in javascript.

And the code you share is an angularjs controller, which is a javascript function.

For details; google.

Answer (score 0):

```
    not sure, but I think this is help you
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    });
    </script>
```

or

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.spices = [{"name":"pasilla", "spiciness":"mild"},
                   {"name":"jalapeno", "spiciness":"hot hot hot!"},
                   {"name":"habanero", "spiciness":"LAVA HOT!!"}];
  $scope.spice = "habanero";
});
```